# Calculate the sum when the average is increasing

Tags: functions, summation

Please excuse my "stupid" question. I got quite confused trying to solve this.

An average daily revenue is increasing from $f(1) = a = 1$ on the first day, to $f(30) = b = 10$ at the end of the month. How can I calculate the sum of monthly income? I failed to find the exact formula. (Supposedly the average increase is linear.)

Comment: The way I read this is: On day 30 the average daily revenue was 10.  So the monthly revenue was 30*10 = 300. (30 days at an average of 30 per day.)  That's all.  On the first day they only made 1 but they made up for it later.

Comment: @fleablood i think that's not quite correct, check the other answers

Comment: If the other answers are correct then the question was stated incorrectly.  If the "average daily revenue" is f(n) then on f(30) "the average daily revenue" is 10.  If that revenue is truly the *AVERAGE* daily revenue then the monthly sum is 30*AVERAGE = 300.  If instead f(30) is *not* the *AVERAGE* but the total for *THAT* day, then it is an entirely different (and much more sensible) question.  In that case the actual average is 5.5 (NOT 10) the total is 30 *5.5 = 165.  If that is the intended answer it was stated WRONG.

Comment: Please edit your question.  The *AVERAGE* daily income is *NOT* increasing from 1 to 10.  On day 30 the *AVERAGE* income is *NOT* 10.  The DAILY income for day 30 is 10, but for every other day it was smaller so the AVERAGE daily income is *smaller* than 10.  Indeed it is only 5.5.  Your question *IS* stated incorrectly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I have understood well, you want to compute
$$1+\cdots+10$$
where this sum has $30$ terms and they are equally spaced.

The second term is
$$1+d$$
where $d$ is how much you add every day.

The second-to-last term is
$$10-d$$

If you sum the first and the last, the second and the second-to-last, etc, you always get $11$. And you can make $15$ of these pairs. The sum is
$$15\cdot11=165$$

See [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arithmetic_progression#Sum) for more information.

Comment: You understood me correctly sir Thank you! It comes actually to simply calculating the total average and multiply by the days count: (1 + 10) / 2 x 30 = 165 :)

Comment: If he understood you correctly than you stated it wrong.  You said "An average daily revenue is increasing" when what you meant was "A daily revenue".  If the *average* daily revenue was 10 then the total sum is 30*10 and it doesn't matter what the average or individual totals were on any day; the *average* was 10.  That clearly was not what you meant but it *is* what you said.

Comment: @fleablood: The average way not 10. The average is as he expressed it 1+d each day, having the income in the last day = 1 + (30 - 1)d

Comment: If that is the income of day 30 then it is *NOT* the average daily income for the month.  If that *is* the average daily income for the month then that is *not* the income of day 30.  If the average daily income for k days is m then the total income for k days is k x m.  That is the *definition* of average.  It is unavoidable.

Answer (score 1):

I believe the total revenue for the month is 165.

Suppose the revenue increases by $d$ each day. Then you will receive $a$ the first day, $a+d$ the second day, $a+2d$ the third day, etc., up to $a+29d$ on the thirtieth day.

So since $a=1$ and $a+29d=10$, you have that $d=9/29$.

The total revenue for all days in the month is
$$a+(a+d)+(a+2d)+(a+3d)+\cdots+(a+29d)$$
$$=\underbrace{(a+a+\cdots+a)}_{30\textrm{ terms}}+(1+2+\cdots+29)d$$
$$=30a+\left(\tfrac{29(30)}{2}\right)d$$
$$=30(1)+\left(\tfrac{29(30)}{2}\right)\left(\tfrac{9}{29}\right)$$
$$=30+9(15)=\boxed{165}$$
(Recall that $1+2+3+\cdots+n=\frac{n(n+1)}{2}$ to compute the sum $1+2+\cdots+29$ above.)

Comment: Except the very first sentence said "AVERAGE daily revenue" so the revenue recieved on day 30 is not 10.  10 is the average of revenues from day 1 to day thirty.  So $a + 29 \ne 10$.  Instead $\frac{30a + \frac{29*30}2d}{30} = a + 29d/2= 10$.  So $d = 18/29$ and and the revenue on day 30 is 19.  which *averages* to 10 per day.  For a monthly total of 30*10 = 300.

Answer (score 0):

If the average after $30$ days is $10$ per day, then the sum after $30$ days is $30*10 =300$.

That's what average means:  $average = \frac{sum}{numer of days}$ so $sum = average*number of days$.

Now if the average is increasing linearly that means:  Each day the average increases by $9/29$.  (From day 1 to day 30 it increased from 1 to 10.  That's an increase of 9 over 29 days.)

That means on day 29 the average revenue was $1 + 28*9/29 = 9 +20/29$ which means in $29$ days the total revenue was $29(9+20/29) = 281$.  So the revenue on day 30 was $300 - 281 = 19$.

In fact, each day the revenue increases by $18/29$.  On day $n$ the *average* revenue is $1 + (n-1)\frac 9{29}$ so the *total* revenue is $n (1 + (n-1)\frac 9{29})$ if you subtract the total revenue up to the previous day $(n-1)(1 + (n-2)\frac 9{29}$ you get the  revenue for day $n$ is $1 + (n-1)18/29$.